# BMP screenshot in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I´m trying to take a screenshot in BMP format of the application I´m running. It takes well the screenshot when it is windowed, doesn´t matter the size of the window it works well. But, when I put my application in fullscreen using glutFullScreen() it doesn´t save the BMP file properly. Any ideas why does it happen?

This is the function call

```
hacerCaptura(ancho, alto);
```

where

```
ancho = glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_WIDTH);
alto  = glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_HEIGHT);
```

Here is the code:

```
    void hacerCaptura(int anchura, int altura)
{
    BMP_Data = malloc (anchura * altura * 3);
    memset (BMP_Data, 0, anchura * altura * 3);

    glReadPixels (0, 0, anchura, altura, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, BMP_Data);
    guardaBMP ("captura.bmp", anchura, altura, (unsigned char*)BMP_Data);

    free (BMP_Data);
}


    int guardaBMP (char *filename, int anchura, int altura, unsigned char *BMP_Data)
{
    FILE *punteroFich;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER infoBMP;
    BITMAPFILEHEADER cabeceraBMP;
    unsigned int contador;
    unsigned char tempRGB;

    punteroFich = fopen (filename, "wb"); 
    if (!punteroFich)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    cabeceraBMP.bfOffBits = sizeof (BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof (BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    cabeceraBMP.bfReserved1 = 0;
    cabeceraBMP.bfReserved2 = 0;
    cabeceraBMP.bfSize = sizeof (BITMAPFILEHEADER);
    cabeceraBMP.bfType = 0x4D42; 

    infoBMP.biBitCount = 24;
    infoBMP.biClrImportant = 0;
    infoBMP.biClrUsed = 0;
    infoBMP.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    infoBMP.biHeight = altura;
    infoBMP.biPlanes = 1;
    infoBMP.biSize = sizeof (BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    infoBMP.biSizeImage = anchura * abs (altura) * 3;
    infoBMP.biWidth = anchura;
    infoBMP.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    infoBMP.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;

    for (contador = 0; contador < infoBMP.biSizeImage; contador += 3)
    {
        tempRGB = BMP_Data [contador];
        BMP_Data [contador] = BMP_Data [contador + 2];
        BMP_Data [contador + 2] = tempRGB;
    }

    fwrite (&cabeceraBMP, 1, sizeof (BITMAPFILEHEADER), punteroFich);
    fwrite (&infoBMP, 1, sizeof (BITMAPINFOHEADER), punteroFich);
    fwrite (BMP_Data, 1, infoBMP.biSizeImage, punteroFich);

    fclose (punteroFich);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: "it doesn´t save the BMP file properly" is really vague. What exactly is wrong? The file isn't created at all? The file is corrupted? The image is the wrong size?

Comment: Sorry about that. The file is created, it isn´t empty but the format is not correct, that´s what is says.

Comment: What says the format is not correct?

Comment: The photo application of Windows 10 when trying to see if it worked. It doesn´t open with photoshop or whatever neither.

Comment: This question should probably be tagged 'C', rather than 'C++'. I don't see a single C++ concept in use in this code, and the advice I would offer for fixing it would differ based on the platform.

Comment: Your call to `glReadPixels` should probably use `GL_BGR` rather than `GL_RGB`, if you're just going to flip the red + blue pixels later anyways. Might save some processing time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the offending line is this one:

```
cabeceraBMP.bfSize = sizeof (BITMAPFILEHEADER);
```

From the [documentation for BITMAPFILEHEADER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183374(v=vs.85).aspx):

> **bfSize**
> The size, in bytes, of the bitmap file.

So the correct value for `bfSize` is `sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + anchura * altura * 3`.

I tested this with a small, 20x20 bitmap I created to test with:

[image: Raw Data Values of bitmap image]

Which matches the values you'd expect based on the [standardized bitmap format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Bitmap_file_header).

I haven't sanity-checked all your other required fields, but my advice is that you refer to the documentation pages and make sure you're substituting in the correct values for all of those fields.

## Edit:

There's another potential issue that may be affecting your image output.

The Bitmap format expects all your rows of bitmap data to be aligned with up to 3 bytes of padding depending on the actual row length, so that each row of data is a multiple of four bytes. This isn't a big deal if your image width is a multiple of 4 (like 1920x1080) but could become a problem if you're using a resolution that doesn't line up neatly like that (like 1366x768, which is a very common pre-1080p resolution). If your resolution is unusual, check and make sure the data from `glReadPixels` is properly padded, and if it isn't, transform it so that it is.

Comment: Thank you very much. There was a problem with size as you pointed out. Also, as you said in your edit, I had to pad the data from glReadPixels to make my image width multiple of 4. Now, all is working fine.